Rmarkdown whitespace in Word output creates hyperlink
From within a code chunk I'd like to write text with one or more whitespace between words. The Rmarkdown output is Word document. The use of cat() and &nbsp; has worked well, but unwanted hyperlinks are created in the following case:
---
title: ''
output: word_document
---

```{r, results = 'asis'}
cat("Notes:&nbsp;")
cat("notes:&nbsp;&nbsp;")
cat("Notes:&nbsp;For&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;the")
cat("Note:&nbsp;For&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;the")
```

In the Word output this produces:
Notes: ; formatted as hyperlink, note the addition of semicolon
notes:  ; also hyperlink, it preserves the two spaces but still adds semicolon
Notes: For   the the number of whitespaces is correct and there is no added semicolon, but it's still an hyperlink
Note: For   the this last case shows that all works well if you just use a slightly different word
How do I achieve Notes: For   the without creating hyperlinks and without the semicolon addition? I already disabled the Word option that automatically formats paths as hyperlinks. Why is this particular word creating this behaviour and are there other words that would also do this?

Following this post, one option would be to use the Unicode symbol \u00a0 to add a non breaking space:
---
title: ''
output: word_document
---

```{r, results = 'asis', echo=FALSE}
cat("Notes:\u00a0\n\n")
cat("notes:\u00a0\u00a0\n\n")
cat("Notes:\u00a0For\u00a0\u00a0\u00a0the\n\n")
cat("Note:\u00a0For\u00a0\u00a0\u00a0the\n\n")
```



Thank you!! It actually works nicely! I had tried with "\ua0" but that worked well only if no other characters followed.

Although the mistery remains: why this particular word does that? maybe the use of " " is meant for HTML, so its behaviour in other formats can be unpredictable?
